# Where does ReadOnlyStringWrapper.ReadOnlyPropertyImpl takes oldValue for ChangeListener from?

Tags: java, javafx

I am studying `ReadOnlyStringWrapper.ReadOnlyPropertyImpl` class of JavaFX11 that is:

```
private class ReadOnlyPropertyImpl extends ReadOnlyStringPropertyBase {

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return ReadOnlyStringWrapper.this.get();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getBean() {
        return ReadOnlyStringWrapper.this.getBean();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return ReadOnlyStringWrapper.this.getName();
    }
};
```

The instance of `ReadOnlyPropertyImpl` is returned to client that can work with it in `read only` mode. The thing I can't understand is where `ReadOnlyPropertyImpl` will take the `oldValue` for `ChangeListener`. As we see it overrides only `get` method for current value, that is taken from the wrapper. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Note that _all_ of the various `XXXPropertyBase`, `ReadOnlyXXXPropertyBase`, and `ObservableValueBase` classes store the old value in the manner explained in the accepted answer, not just the mentioned `ReadOnlyPropertyImpl`.

Comment: @Slaw Ok, thank you for the note.

Comment: @Slaw BTW, maybe you can advise me something. In Java we have Integer and int. So `IntegerPropertyBase` has `set(int)` and `setValue(Number)`. How do you think, if we port javafx to JavaScript, what must we have for `NumberPropertyBase` `set` and `setValue`, taking into consideration that in JS we have `number` primitive and `Number` object. I suppose that in JS we must `NumberPropertyBase.set(number)` and `NumberPropertyBase.setValue(Number)`. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript (or TypeScript) to give a proper opinion, but if `Number` and `number` really are corollaries to `Integer` and `int`, respectively, then I would tend to agree. You may want to ask a new question to get feedback from people knowledgeable in JavaScript/TypeScript.

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to make the same in TypeScript, because 1) ObservableValue<T> has getValue():T, but when we use it in ObservableNumberValue we use it as ObservableValue<number>, see here https://github.com/PavelKastornyy/script4j/blob/master/modules/script4jfx.base/src/script4jfx/beans/value/ObservableNumberValue.ts  2) Object classes are not assignable to their  primitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current value is stored in the helper class that is used for the event handling, see `com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper`. E.g. if you take a look at the concrete implementation in the `SingleChange` static inner class:

```
private T currentValue;

...

@Override
protected void fireValueChangedEvent() {
    final T oldValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = observable.getValue();

    ...
    listener.changed(observable, oldValue, currentValue);
    ...
}
```

`Generic`, the other class for handling change events has a similar implementation.

Adding listeners results in the creation of a `ExpressionHelper` instance (or the modification of a existing one) and this this object is responsible for invoking event handlers. (The `ExpressionHandler` is stored in a field of the property object, in this case in `ReadOnlyStringPropertyBase`'s `helper` field.)